# How to track down access violation "at address 00000000" in third party software using MadExcept of Sysinternals ProcessMonitor?

Tags: delphi, access-violation, sysinternals, procmon, madexcept

Access violation "at address 00000000" started appear to my Delphi 2009 installation. I started ProcessMonitor https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon and filtered events by bds.exe Process Name and the log is manageable. There were some records about missing registry entries and files not accesible if searched by MS OLE classid. But otherwise there was no report about access violation. I have doubts that ProcessMonitor is suitable for the catching AV errors and viewing call stack that leads to it.

I have used MadExcel in my own Delphi applications and I liked the call stacks etc it provided.

My question is - is there possibility to start MadExcept as standalone program and ask it to monitor call stacks of other program (Delphi 2009 instance bds.exe in my case) and catch/report access violation?

Comment: No. MadExcept has to be compiled into the application that you're trying to debug. There is no call stack in an application running outside the debugger that can be accessed by a different application. As far as the exception goes, it's caused by trying to use or read from a null pointer, and you couldn't fix it anyway without the source for the third-party software. Have you contacted the third-party vendor to report the issue?

Comment: If you're getting the exception in the IDE itself, chances are you've got a misbehaving third-party component/expert/wizard that's causing it. You can test for that by exiting the IDE, and start it from the command line with `bds -r foo`, which starts the IDE with a new, blank session with new registry keys and no third-party packages loaded. You can start adding your components back in one at a time until the problem reappears, at which point you can try to address the issue. The `-r foo` simply creates new registry entries in a section named `foo`, so it only takes effect when `-r` is used.

Comment: And if it's not a misbehaving third-party component/wizard/etc, then it could also be that either the IDE installation itself or some component of Windows that it depends upon is itself corrupted somehow.  If all else fails, try a clean re-install of D2009.  If that fails, try a clean install of Windows.

Comment: Wouldn't be the first error of BDS.exe itself...

Comment: Why not attach a debugger to BDS.exe and wait for the exception to happen? Then you have the call stack